# Declaring Multiple Singletons in 1 class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a situation where I may need to declare two singletons in a class

```
class ImageManager {

    static var imageCache = NSCache()

    static var imageManager = ImageManager()

    (...)
}
```

Is there any danger to this ?

Comment: Why would you 'need' to do that? Standard singleton comments apply...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, there is no problem with multiple static variables in a single class. Only one of them should be called *singleton* - namely, the `imageManager`, because that's the instance that's going to be unique in your design.

However, if `ImageManager` need the exclusive use of `NSCache`, it is better to make `imageCache` an instance property of `ImageManager`. Should other static methods need to access the cache, they could always gain access to it through `imageManager.imageCache`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "exclusive use of `NSCache`" ?

Comment: @rayjohn By "exclusive use" I mean that the instance of `NSCache` called `imageCache` is not going to be used by other classes directly, but only through methods of `ImageManager`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem,but it is not recommended,you can code like this

```
class ImageManager {
    var imageCache = NSCache()
    static var imageManager = ImageManager()
}
```

and get the imageCache like this

```
ImageManage.imageManager.imageCache
```